# Is accessing container element time-consuming?

Tags: c++

I want to count GCD of integers and save them. I find that the time consuming part is not to calculate GCD but to save result to the map. Do I use std::map in a bad way?

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "timer.h"

using namespace std;

int gcd (int a, int b)
{
    int temp;
    while (b != 0)
    {
        temp = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    return(a);
}

int main() {
    map<int,int> res;
    {
        Timer timer;
        for(int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 2; j < 10000; j++)
                res[gcd(i,j)]++;
        }
    }

    {
        Timer timer;
        for(int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 2; j < 10000; j++)
                gcd(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

6627099us(6627.1ms)

0us(0ms)

Comment: The second one does nothing, and the compiler is free to remove it.

Comment: Your second loop being optimized away aside `std::map` is red-black tree whcih is O(logN). Consider using `std::undordered_map` which is `O(1)` ammortized. With the amount you are computing the choice of container likely makes a difference. With keys being integers you wouldn't see many collisions.

Comment: I try std::undordered_map, it takes 6509176us(6509.18ms), almost same as std::map.

Comment: Have you enabled optimizations while compiling?

Comment: When I test it, I get 3.2 seconds with ```map``` and 2.6 seconds with ```unordered_map```. The speedup may be slower than expected because the GCD algorithm keeps the division unit occupied and that is also needed for the hashmap in  ```unordered_map```. Meanwhile the ```map``` spends most of its time pointer chasing while GCD does no memory operations whatsoever. So that latency can be hidden by out-of-order execution.

Comment: BTW: Using a vector would be even faster since you are dealing with small-ish integers that populate their range rather densely. In my tests about 2.4 seconds

Answer (score 2):

You should use some real benchmarking library to test this kind of code. In your particular case, the second loop where you discard the results of `gcd` was probably optimized away. With [quickbench](https://quick-bench.com/q/54hGcS4MvjO7ZyEJGk1VXf9a7zA) I see not that much difference between running just the algorithm and storing the results in `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. I used randomized integers for testing, which is maybe not the best for GCD algorithm, but you can try other approaches.

Code under benchmark without storage:

```
constexpr int N = 10000;
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(1, N);
benchmark::DoNotOptimize(gcd(distrib(gen), distrib(gen)));
```

and with storage:

```
benchmark::DoNotOptimize(res[gcd(distrib(gen), distrib(gen))]++);
```

Results:

[image: results]

Answer (score 2):

You are using `std::map` correctly.  However, you are using an inefficient container for your problem.  Given that the possible values of gcd(x,y) are bounded by N, a `std::vector` would be the most efficient container to store the results.

Specifically,

```
int main() {
    const int N = 10'000;
    std::vector<int> res(N, 0); // initialize to N elements with value 0.
    ...
}
```

Using parallelism will speed up the program even further.  Each thread would have it's own `std::vector` to compute local results.  Once a thread is finished, the results would be added to the `result` vector in a thread-safe manner (e.g. using `std::mutex`).